# Access key href title depending on browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this, a search bar activated by access key s, trouble is that each browser has different combination, I have put title [alt+s] as it's true for Chrome, but if someone is browsing with Firefox that won't work. I'm wondering how to make title dynamic, showing right combination for user's browser?

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" accesskey="s" class="togglesearch" title="[alt+s]" >&#128269;</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little snippet should do the trick. Sadly `HTMLElement.accessKeyLabel` is only available in FF, but for the other browsers, `"Alt + accessKey` should work.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[accesskey]'), node => {
  node.title += " [" + (node.accessKeyLabel || "alt+" + node.accessKey) + "]"
});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" accesskey="s" title="Search" class="togglesearch" >&#128269;</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, maybe not perfect but covers two most popular browsers so it's good enough for me.